# Hosting DNN application in IIS , getting 404 error on login click

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN ,

I have a website which is being developed using DNN.
 I have hosted this application in IIS , I get the home page. But when I click on login or register or any menu's present in the home page I get 404 error which says "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I am using IIS 7.5 , .Net 4.5

I have given the proper path of application and have access to all folders of the application

I don't know what is the issue . Please help how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the DNN documentation? Perhaps you're running on IIS 7, in Integrated mode, and your configuration uses Classic mode? When posting questions about web applications, it's helpful if you say what version of IIS you're using, what version of ASP.NET, whether you're on integrated or classic mode and more helpful information. Is the 404 made by IIS's StaticFileHandler, or something inside DNN? If it's in StaticFileHandler, it basically means it didn't trigger any other handler along the way, which usually means bad configuration.

Comment: Hi..sorry i din mention all these details..my bad..I am running it on IIS 7 and its ASP.net v4.0 and it is integrated mode..However this issue was resolved once I formated my system. I really din't know what was the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

When you see this there's an issue with routing that is causing the advanced urls not to work.

The only consistent way I've found to fix this is to make sure your modules node in your web.config has runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" but it seems [there are performance implications with doing this.](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance you changed the Login page for the site to something other than the default page?

Go to `Site Settings`, `Advanced Settings` and check your `Login Page`.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS core engine uses preconditions to determine when to enable a particular module. Performance reasons, for example, might determine that you only want to execute managed modules for requests that also go to a managed handler. The precondition in the following example (precondition="managedHandler") only enables the forms authentication module for requests that are also handled by a managed handler, such as requests to .aspx or .asmx files:

If you remove the attribute precondition="managedHandler", Forms Authentication also applies to content that is not served by managed handlers, such as .html, .jpg, .doc, but also for classic ASP (.asp) or PHP (.php) extensions. See "How to Take Advantage of IIS Integrated Pipeline" for an example of enabling ASP.NET modules to run for all content.

You can also use a shortcut to enable all managed (ASP.NET) modules to run for all requests in your application, regardless of the "managedHandler" precondition.

To enable all managed modules to run for all requests without configuring each module entry to remove the "managedHandler" precondition, use the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests property in the  section:

When you use this property, the "managedHandler" precondition has no effect and all managed modules run for all requests.